# firebase crash reporting report a fatal error but with 100% crash free

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using `firebase` crash reporting and i see a `NullPointerException`
Fatal Issue but it has a ~100% Crash free.

How can it be fatal without a crashe repoted?